# Difference in size apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I wrote a code in Java to read an excel(.xlsx) file and save the same file with different name. The code is working fine but the size of original and generated excel is different. I got the problem as on saving the original, the excel is losing some data. But when I opened the generated file through Ms Excel it get restored to its original size. What could I use in my code so that no data is lost?
Code is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class MyExcel {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\test.xlsx"));

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
        XSSFRow row1 = sheet.getRow(1);
        XSSFCell cell1 = row1.getCell(1);
        cell1.setCellValue("Mahesh");
        XSSFRow row2 = sheet.getRow(2);
        XSSFCell cell2 = row2.getCell(1);
        cell2.setCellValue("Ramesh");

        OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\test_new.xlsx"));

        workbook.write(fos);
        fis.close();
        fos.close();

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

The image shows the different in size of two files.[image: Size Difference]

[image]

Comment: This does not mean that the actual cell data is lost because the output file generated by `XSSFWorkbook` might be stripped of some unneeded meta information.

Comment: Yes,I want that metadata also. The actual data is not lost but metadata is lost.

Comment: Can you determine which metadata is lost? What are you missing in the new created Excel file?

Comment: Why don't you `Files.copy`  directly if you want an exact copy?

Comment: @kism3t No I am not able to get what metadata is lost.May be that is being added by MS excel internally is lost.

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava so what exactly is the problem here? Office *x formats are very complicated and Microsoft's implementations may differ from the standard.

Comment: As @ΔλЛ mentions .. I do not see any problem here. If you do not miss anything, all is good. If you want to make a copy then follow @ RC suggestions and copy the file with File utils.

Comment: @kism3t This loss of metadata is affecting other operation and when I am using FileUtils, Ms Excel is throwing error. See in edit.

Comment: Could you explain "other operations". As we and you do not know what we are looking and what is missing, it is hard to help.

Comment: I have another program that is not taking the generated file as input saying some data are missing. The only problem is the size of the file. How do I get the original size in the generated file?

Comment: If all you want is to copy one excel file into other you are already doing it with FileUtils, and looks like its copying the file correctly. Now `workbook.write(fos);` code is getting executed its corrupting the file metadata. You can remove `workbook.write(fos);` from your code and check its working or not

Comment: @Shiva The problem is with file size only. Please check the code now.